# Paypal Delayed Chained payment pay key "EXPIRED" error in "Pay" request

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have been using PayPal Delayed Chained payment. In case first payment is successful save the respondent pay key in DB. After some days I pay the amount to second receiver I have get error " payKey AP-7LM30647VL197891T is expired ". 
How to pay the amount to second reciever.
Paypal Response:

```
PayPal\Types\AP\ExecutePaymentResponse Object
(
    [responseEnvelope] => PayPal\Types\Common\ResponseEnvelope Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 2016-06-28T02:34:58.143-07:00
            [ack] => Failure
            [correlationId] => c804e78cabc5e
            [build] => 23046607
        )
    [paymentExecStatus] => 
    [payErrorList] => 
    [postPaymentDisclosureList] => 
    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorData Object
                (
                    [errorId] => 580022
                    [domain] => PLATFORM
                    [subdomain] => Application
                    [severity] => Error
                    [category] => Application
                    [message] => payKey AP-7LM30647VL197891T is expired
                    [exceptionId] => 
                    [parameter] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => PayPal\Types\Common\ErrorParameter Object
                                (
                                    [name] => 
                                    [value] => AP-7LM30647VL197891T
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```